# Least Cost Grid to Connect a Start Point to End Points

Tags: qgis, cost-path, least-cost

I am looking for a method or plugin to find the least cost electrical grid to connect villages (end points) from a point on a existing grid (start point) in QGIS.

I tried the "Least Cost Path" plugin in QGIS (see the example in the picture below: end points in blue and start point in red). The raster used in this case is constant over the area with a pixel resolution of 10mx10m. However, the result I get with this plugin is not good (red lines).

[image]

I should get something like that which is the shortest possible line to connect the 3 point in the example:

[image]

Do you know other methods or plugins in QGIS that would work better for this application?